# Updating the DOM with new edited text without updating the backend of the single page application

Tags: javascript, oop, dom, dom-events, es6-class

I am trying to create a single page application for keeping recipes and ingredients together. A user creates a recipe and under the recipe they can create ingredients and then click a button to bring up a form to edit the ingredients. For some reason when I use the edit button the original data is still there and the edit is appended to the front of it. How do I erase the original so that only the edit is showing up on the DOM? I don't want to replace on the server I just want to update the front end to display the new data to the user. Code and git repos are below.

```
  
    constructor(ingredient) {
        this.recipe_id = ingredient.recipe_id
        this.name = ingredient.name
        this.id = ingredient.id
        
    }

    static createIngredient(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        const ingredientInput = e.target.children[0].value
        const ingredientList = e.target.nextElementSibling
        const recipeId = e.target.parentElement.dataset.id

        Ingredient.submitIngredient(ingredientInput, ingredientList, recipeId)

        e.target.reset()
    }

    renderIngredient(ingredientList){
        const li = document.createElement('li')
        li.dataset.id = this.recipe_id
        li.innerText = this.name
      
        const deleteBtn = document.createElement('button')
        deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", this.deleteIngredient)
        deleteBtn.innerText = "X"
        li.appendChild(deleteBtn)
        ingredientList.appendChild(li)

        const editBtn = document.createElement('button')
        editBtn.addEventListener("click", this.editIngredient.bind(this))
        editBtn.innerText = "Edit"
        li.appendChild(editBtn)
        ingredientList.appendChild(li)


    }
    
    static submitIngredient(ingredient, ingredientList, recipeId){
        fetch(ingredientUrl, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: ingredient, 
                recipe_id: recipeId
            })
        }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(ingredient => {
            let newIngredient = new Ingredient(ingredient)
            newIngredient.renderIngredient(ingredientList)
        })
    }

    
    deleteIngredient(){
        const ingredientId = this.parentElement.dataset.id
        fetch(`${recipeUrl}/${ingredientId}`, {
            method: "DELETE"
        })
        this.parentElement.remove()
    }
   
    
   
    
    editIngredient(){
        const editForm = document.createElement("form")
        editForm.id = "edit-form"
        const editInput = document.createElement("input")
        editInput.id = "edit-input"
        
        const editBtn = document.createElement('button')
        editBtn.innerText = "Submit"
        editForm.addEventListener("submit", this.updateIngredient)
        editForm.append(editInput, editBtn)
        event.target.parentElement.appendChild(editForm)

        
    }
    
     updateIngredient(){
    event.preventDefault()
    let newName = document.getElementById('edit-input').value;
    event.target.parentElement.innerHTML = event.target.parentElement.innerHTML.replace(this.name, newName);
    this.name = newName;
    document.getElementById('edit-form').outerHTML = ""
```

https://github.com/MisterAnthropy/recipe-app-frontend
https://github.com/MisterAnthropy/recipe-app-backend

Comment: Did you think about using local or sessionStorage to store the users data? You could save the temporary data there and use it to update your front end so that your back end would be intact.

Comment: Yes I did give that a try but it still did not solve the issue of my frontend still displaying the old data that was there before the edit.